# Resource id error when attempting a RIGHT(string, int)

Tags: php, mysql

I have a db with 2 tables:

```
db: scwdb
Table 1: tblspecies 
field: txtSpeciesList (ex: "Maple")

Table 2: tblsplintersbowlinventory
field: txtProductBowlCode (ex: "MapleSpTi12-025")
field: txtProductPrimarySpecies - which is blank, it is the target field to be filled
```

And some PHP MySQL code:

```
    mysql_select_db("scwdb", $con);

$query = "SELECT * FROM tblspecies"; 

$species = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($species)){

    $wood = $row['txtSpeciesList'];
    $seq = mysql_query('SELECT txtProductBowlCode, RIGHT(txtProductBowlCode,6) FROM tblsplintersbowlinventory');

    echo "Species: ". $row['txtSpeciesList'];
    echo "<br />";
    echo "Wood: ". $wood;
    echo "<br />";
    echo "Seq: ". $seq;
    echo "<br />";
```

Basically I read tblspecies and for each txtSpeciesList I get the $species value and loop through tblsplintersbowlinventory and for every time the txtProductBowlCode value includes the $species value I update txtProductPrimarySpecies with that value.

That works just fine to set the txtProductPrimarySpecies to the $species value - but I also want to append the last 6 chars of the txtProductBowlCode (ex: MapleSpTi12-025 yields 12-025) and append that onto the $species value (Mpale) and then update txtProductPrimarySpecies with the new combined value (Maple12-025).

This also runs, but I get the following output:

```
Species: Ash
Wood: Ash
Seq: Resource id #5
```

It show the species, but for some reason the

```
$seq = mysql_query('SELECT txtProductBowlCode, RIGHT(txtProductBowlCode,6) FROM tblsplintersbowlinventory');
```

code gives me "`Resource id #5`" error.

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

you need to do mysql_fetch_array on $seq;

```
$rowSeq = mysql_fetch_array($seq);
print_r($rowSeq);
```

Comment: That gives me:Array ( [0] => Ash07-001 [txtProductBowlCode] => Ash07-001 [1] => 07-001 [RIGHT(txtProductBowlCode,6)] => 07-001 ) Species: Ash
Wood: Ash
Seq: Resource id #5

Comment: OK, I see that the result it gives is 07-001 which is correct, but why do I still get the Resource ID #5 error?

Comment: Also, I should have mentioned that the Resource ID # jumps by 2 every time this loops...

Comment: this line: echo "Seq: ". $seq;

Comment: Not sure what you mean - that's the line I have. Should I take it out? Why would the print_r show the value and not the echo?

Comment: And using the $rowSeq = mysql_fetch_array($seq); still doesn't give me the value to append to the $species...

Comment: that line is giving you the resource #4

Comment: I seem to have misread your first code - I've changed the $seq in the echo to $rowSeq and now it echos the line "Seq: Array"...Obviously I'm missing something basic like TYPE but I don't see it...